# How to load bundled file in system import in angular 2 using Gulp : Error: Multiple anonymous System.register calls in module

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular, gulp, gulp-concat

I have a angular 2 application with typescript which generates js files .

Recently I installed npm and gulp and written tasks to bundle all js files in to single now how to load that file?

**Earlier in my index.html page:**   //which works where main  is the  component which bootstraps appComponent

```
<script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js',
                    defaultJSExtensions: true
                }
            }
        });
        debugger;
        //System.import('Scripts/main')
        System.import('app/V1/components/main')
              .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

My Gulp task:

```
var config = {
    src: ['app/**/*.js'],
    dest: ['Scripts/']
};

gulp.task('bundle', function () {

    console.log('testing');
    return gulp.src(config.src)
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('app/'));
})
```

When I run this gulp task it generates all.min.js but how to use this now i.e how to remove that main.js in System.import and load this

```
<script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js',
                    defaultJSExtensions: true
                }
            },
            map: {
                immutable: 'app/all.min.js'
            }
        });
        debugger;
        //System.import('Scripts/main')
        System.import('app/all.min')
              .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

I tried this way which is throwing error as

Error: Multiple anonymous System.register calls in module http://localhost:55308/app/all.min.js. If loading a bundle, ensure all the System.register calls are named.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better solution for bundling files for use with system.js. There is a handy library called [systemjs-builder](https://github.com/systemjs/builder). You can easily use it with gulp.

First you need to extract your system.js script in to a separate file. Then you can use this task to generate the concatenated js.

```
gulp.task('system', () => {
    var builder = new systemBuilder();

    return builder.loadConfig('./system.config.js') // Name of your system js file
        .then(() => builder.buildStatic('app',  'total.js'))
```

});

Now you have the concatenated files as well as the system.js configuration needed to run it, every thing should work fine at this point. However you will need to use a separate library to uglify the js. [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) should work fine.

Here is an example task:

```
gulp.task('build', ['system'], () => {
    return gulp.src([
        'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js',
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
        'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
        'total.js'
    ])
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
    });
```

Now if you run `gulp build` and include the genrated main.js in to your index.html (removing all the other scripts), everything should work.

Comment: Thank you for your time , you mean the last script which I placed i.e System.config on need to be placed in separate which you are referring as system js file i.e system.config.js right ???

Comment: What is my total.js here and main .js here? It would be great if you mention Systemjs file too

Comment: the total.js is all of the app files, and main.js are the compiled and uglified files along with all of your dependencies. Your system.config.js should look something like this (check out the system.config.js at the bottom of the page): https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html